# Erro em arquivo de conexão php para database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

**Erros:**

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/a9630388/public_html/register.php
>   **on line 7**
>
> Free Web Hosting
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt,
>   boolean given in /home/a9630388/public_html/register.php **on line 8**
>
> Free Web Hosting {"success":true}

**Código:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("CONFIDENCIAL");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (email, senha) VALUES(?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $email, $senha);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Diz que o erro é na linha 7 e 8. Por que isso aparece? qual o problema?

Comment: como realizo esse teste?

Comment: Fiz as alterações e retornou este erro:

NULL NULL 
PHP Error Message

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/a9630388/public_html/register.php on line 10

Free Web Hosting

PHP Error Message

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/a9630388/public_html/register.php on line 11

Free Web Hosting
{"success":true}

Comment: sim, escrevi eles

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44311/discussion-between-allan-andrade-and-gorick-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um erro visível é o segundo parâmetro de [**mysqli_stmt_bind_param**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), que no seu caso deveria ser "ss", representando string e string para login e senha respectivamente.

Logo, você deve substituir: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $email, $senha);`

Por: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $senha);`

Além disso, se ao executar `var_dump($_POST);` estiver retornando `array(0) { }`, indica que os dados não estão sendo postados e por este motivo seu código continua a apresentar erro.

Comment: consertei e mesmo assim persiste o problema!